# C++ multiple inheritance - diamond with templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, virtual

I've got a problem when inheriting from multiple instances of a template.

My class Bridge tries to inherit from 2 instances of BridgeTemplate, so when we try to call the BridgeTemplate's 'set' function, the compiler rises an error ("ambiguous..."). However, everything works ok if Bridge inherits from only 1 instance.

Below, a piece of code from both the template and class Bridge. Thanks in advance

```
template <class DataType, class DataWriter>
class BridgeTemplate : public BridgeGeneric
{
    public:
        void set(DataType a, DataWriter b)
        {
            std::cout << "a: " << a << "; b: " << b << std::endl;
        }
...
};

class Bridge : public virtual BridgeTemplate<int,float>, public virtual BridgeTemplate<float,int>
{
...
}
```

Comment: So if you do what you are doing you get a compiler error. What about reading the exact message or at least post it here. http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking about a compiler error, always include the complete error text, and also code to reproduce the error (ideally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: Notes: you have `virtual` in the wrong place, where it can't do any good any more. If you want `BridgeGeneric` to only be present once, you have to derive from it virtually. I also suspect you're getting the error simply because the overload resolution is ambiguous, and would be the same if no inheritance was involved. But that's why we need reproducing code to tell.

Comment: do you have to inherit? if you just need access to functionality from BridgeTemplate, then it will be easier to use composition (i.e. have a member of that type) rather than inheritance.

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths That would require writing wrapper functions. Especially in template code, inheritance without any virtual members is an accepted way of composing a class's interface.

Comment: You could do `bridge.BridgeTemplate<int, float>::set(1, 2);` but I can see how that would get tiresome fast.

Comment: Your error is because you call the set function like this: `set(3,5)` (or something like that I think). The compiler cannot know whether it is `set(<int>, <float>)` or `set(<float>, <int>)`, hence the error. Either use a cast to explicitely choose the function, or use 2 types that are not ambiguous (like `float` and `std::string`).

Comment: Adding from that: you should definitely post the code calling the function `set()`.

Answer (score 2):

**Argument types do not matter.**

The error message applies to name lookup, not to overload resolution. All overloaded functions must come from the same class or namespace. In order to ensure that, use this pattern:

```
 class Child : public Dad, public Mom {
     using Dad::func;
     using Mom::func;
 };

 // ...

 Child c;
 c.foo(1, 2.3);
```

Because of the `using` declarations, both `func` members are brought to the `Child` namespace and the lookup is no longer ambiguous.